# Простые числа java

Tags: java

Не могу понять как исправить код так, что бы он выводил k количества чисел, а не все простые числа до числа k.

Пример:
При вводе 5 он должен вывести 5 простых чисел(2,3,5,7,11) а не числа до 5 (2,3,5);

Код:

```
//Библиотеки
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

class Okno extends JFrame { // Наследуем JFrame

    // Подготавливаем переменные
    private final JPanel panel;
    private final JButton button;
    private final JTextArea area;
    private final JTextField textArea;

    public Okno() { // Задаем настройки окна
        setSize(400, 1000); // Размер
        setResizable(false); // Изменяемость
        setTitle("Простые числа"); // Имя

        button = new JButton(); // Реализация кнопки
        button.setText("Посчитать"); // Текст на кнопке
        button.addActionListener(this::buttonPressed); // Слушатель
        button.setBounds(10, 500, 230, 60); // Положение и размеры

        area = new JTextArea(5, 10); // Арена для текста
        area.setText("Тут будут циферки");
        area.setBounds(250, 10, 120, 940);
        //Это для красивого переноса
        area.setLineWrap(true);
        area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        area.setEditable(false); // Не изменяема

        textArea = new JTextField(10); // Поле куда вводдим цифры для их обработки
        textArea.setText("");
        textArea.setBounds(10, 400, 230, 60);

        panel = new JPanel(); // Реализуем panel
        panel.setLayout(null); // Задаем слой
        //Добавление элементов на panel
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(textArea);
        panel.add(area);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(area); // Привязка ползунка
        scrollPane.setViewportView(area); // Устанавливаем привязку к JTextArea
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); // Настройка ползунка
        scrollPane.setBounds(250, 10, 120, 940); // Где должен быть

        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER); // добавляем ее на panel

        setContentPane(panel); // Установка panel в Okno
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Выход при закрытии
        setVisible(true); // Видимость
    }
    //Тут просто идет считывание из textArea, вывод в area только простых чисел
    private void buttonPressed(ActionEvent e) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            int k = Integer.parseInt(textArea.getText());

                for (int i = 2; k > i; i++) {
                    int count = 0;
                    for (int j = 2; j <= k && count < 2; ++j) {
                        if (i % j == 0) count++;
                    }
                    if (count < 2) sb.append(i).append("\n");
            }
            area.setText(String.valueOf(sb));
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) { // Если некорректный ввод то выдача ошибки
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Okno.this,
                    "Некорректный ввод данных", "Ошибка"
                    , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

class Okno extends JFrame { // Наследуем JFrame

    // Подготавливаем переменные
    private final JPanel panel;
    private final JButton button;
    private final JTextArea area;
    private final JTextField textArea;

    public Okno() { // Задаем настройки окна
        setSize(400, 1000); // Размер
        setResizable(false); // Изменяемость
        setTitle("Простые числа"); // Имя

        button = new JButton(); // Реализация кнопки
        button.setText("Посчитать"); // Текст на кнопке
        button.addActionListener(this::buttonPressed); // Слушатель
        button.setBounds(10, 500, 230, 60); // Положение и размеры

        area = new JTextArea(5, 10); // Арена для текста
        area.setText("Тут будут циферки");
        area.setBounds(250, 10, 120, 940);
        //Это для красивого переноса
        area.setLineWrap(true);
        area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        area.setEditable(false); // Не изменяема

        textArea = new JTextField(10); // Поле куда вводдим цифры для их обработки
        textArea.setText("");
        textArea.setBounds(10, 400, 230, 60);

        panel = new JPanel(); // Реализуем panel
        panel.setLayout(null); // Задаем слой
        //Добавление элементов на panel
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(textArea);
        panel.add(area);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(area); // Привязка ползунка
        scrollPane.setViewportView(area); // Устанавливаем привязку к JTextArea
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); // Настройка ползунка
        scrollPane.setBounds(250, 10, 120, 940); // Где должен быть

        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER); // добавляем ее на panel

        setContentPane(panel); // Установка panel в Okno
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Выход при закрытии
        setVisible(true); // Видимость
    }

    //Тут просто идет считывание из textArea, вывод в area только простых чисел
    private void buttonPressed(ActionEvent e) {
        //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            int k = Integer.parseInt(textArea.getText());
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 2; k > i; i++) {
                int count = 0;
                for (int j = 2; j <= k && count < 2; ++j) {
                    if (i % j == 0) count++;
                }
                if (count < 2) counter++;//sb.append(i).append("\n");
            }
            //area.setText(String.valueOf(sb));
            area.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) { // Если некорректный ввод то выдача ошибки
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Okno.this,
                    "Некорректный ввод данных", "Ошибка",
                     JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    
}
```